# Carregar o combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Quando salvo um dado no combo box, e nesse combo box tem duas opções (gasolina, diesel, alcool, gas natural)

Quando seleciono diesel e salvo funciona normalmente.

O problema é quando quero carregar o combo box salvo sempre aparece o primeiro valor do combo, ou seja, a gasolina.

Como é que faço para quando o usuário carregar as informações ele possa ver no combo box o valor selecionado por ele?

O código está abaixo

```
public frmCadVeiculo2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Combustivel> itens = new List<Combustivel>();
    itens.Add(new Combustivel() { IDCombustivel = "Ga", Nome = "Gasolina" });
    itens.Add(new Combustivel() { IDCombustivel = "Di", Nome = "Diesel" });
    itens.Add(new Combustivel() { IDCombustivel = "Al", Nome = "Álcool" });
    itens.Add(new Combustivel() { IDCombustivel = "GN", Nome = "Gás Natural" });

    cbTipoCombustivel.DataSource = itens;
    cbTipoCombustivel.ValueMember = "IDCombustivel";
    cbTipoCombustivel.DisplayMember = "Nome";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemente o método abaixo no seu formulário e quando você carregar os dados salvo, passe para o método o combustivel selecionado:

```
private void SelecionarTipoCombustivel(Combustivel combustivel)
{
    cbTipoCombustivel.SelectedValue = combustivel.IDCombustivel;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
public frmCadVeiculo2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Combustivel> itens = new List<Combustivel>();
    itens.Add(new Combustivel() { IDCombustivel = "Ga", Nome = "Gasolina" });
    itens.Add(new Combustivel() { IDCombustivel = "Di", Nome = "Diesel" });
    itens.Add(new Combustivel() { IDCombustivel = "Al", Nome = "Álcool" });
    itens.Add(new Combustivel() { IDCombustivel = "GN", Nome = "Gás Natural" });

    cbTipoCombustivel.DataSource = itens;
    cbTipoCombustivel.ValueMember = "IDCombustivel";
    cbTipoCombustivel.DisplayMember = "Nome";

   //Aqui você faz a leitura da sua fonte de dados onde você salvou a seleção do usuário.
   Combustivel combustivelSelecionado=LerDaFonteDeDados();

   //Aqui faz a seleção do combobox;
   SelecionarTipoCombustivel(combustivelSelecionado);
}
```

Comment: Oi Tiago, blza?
Primeiramente muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda, sanou 70%,
mas estou com mais uma duvida, esse LerDaFonteDeDados() seria a lista de itens?

Comment: Esse método LerDaFonteDeDados()
Se a fonte de dados é a lista
Como implementaria esse método?

Comment: Consegui, Resolveu o problema, Muitissimo obrigado

Comment: A lista é uma fonte de dados de opções do jeito que você fez está certo,porém agora, você precisa de uma fonte de dados do usuário. Por exemplo: você precisa persistir o dados do usuário, assim quando ele reabrir o seu app ele irá ler desta fonte de dados (pode ser arquivo, base de dados e etc...) e irá mostrar para o usuário a seleção dele.

Comment: Consegui, Resolveu o problema, Muitissimo obrigado